# Django Rest Framework gives wrong type serializer field type when derived from properties

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Lets say I have this CartItem and OrderItem model:

```
class CartItem(Model):
    price = DecimalField(..)


class OrderItem(Model):
    cartitem = OneToOneField('CartItem')

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.cartitem.price
```

When using ModelSerializer and let it to determine the fields implicitly to render OrderItem, price field is turned into float type.

eg. `'price': 10.5` but I was expecting to see `'price': '10.5'`

I need to explicitly specify DecimalField in the serializer to generate correct decimal type like this:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    price = DecimalField(...)
```

Am I missing something?

Update: Here is the issue I raised on github:
[Django Rest Framework gives wrong type serializer field type when derived from properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404613/django-rest-framework-gives-wrong-type-serializer-field-type-when-derived-from-p/34405163#34405163)

Comment: What does `repr(OrderItemSerializer())` give when you don't explicitly specify the field?

Comment: `price = ReadOnlyField()`

Comment: Can you share more details: like the current output and the wanted output.

Comment: @DhiaTN added output and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [issue 582](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/582) from DRF repository, starting from the version 2.1.16 DecimalField will return string but also it alters the value.

```py
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> from rest_framework import renderers
>>> 
>>> obj = {'foo': ['bar', 'baz'], 'float': 1.1, 'decimal': Decimal(1.1)}
>>> 
>>> renderers.JSONRenderer().render(obj, 'application/json')
'{"float": 1.1, "decimal": "1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625", "foo": ["bar", "baz"]}'`
```

I will recommend to use custom attribute, instead of `DecimalField` use `SerializerMethodField` :

```py
class OrderItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    price = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_price(self, obj):
        return str(obj.price)
```

Comment: er... I think your answer is missing the main point this question raises.